# Animation with loop

Tags: python, loops, animation, plot

I'd like to do an easy loop that plot 2D points (x[i],y[i]) one after each other, without using the Animation module, in plot window
I tried :

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x[0],y[0])
for i in range(0,9000):
    plt.plot([],[])
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'o')
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.show()
```

But this code plot each point on different graphs that appears every second. How can I have these points on the same graphs sequentially?

Comment: What Animation module?

Comment: The one from matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got experience using plt, but it seems that show() shows currently plotted points then removes them from future shows, as such you will want to show point 1 in frame 1, then 1 and 2, then 1,2,3 and so on:

```
currentLastPoint = 0
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
while currentLastPoint < len(x):
    currentLastPoint += 1
    plt.plot(x[0],y[0])
    plt.plot([],[])
    for i in range(0,currentLastPoint):
        plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'o')
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.show()
```

EDIT:

Rather than reshowing the display every time, just try to draw onto it:

```
currentLastPoint = 0
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
while currentLastPoint < len(x):
    currentLastPoint += 1
    plt.plot(x[0],y[0])
    plt.plot([],[])
    for i in range(0,currentLastPoint):
        plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'o')
    time.sleep(1)
    if currentLastPoint == 1:
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.draw()
```

Comment: Actually this pops up a new plot window after each iteration. I'd like to have point i appearing in the same plot window for all iterations

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your code as the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x[0],y[0])
for i in range(0,100):
    plt.plot([],[])
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'o')
    plt.pause(0.0001)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will plot a sine wave point by point (no animation functions are needed).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n= 50
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
y = np.sin(x)
mx = np.max(x)
nx = np.min(x)
my = max (y)
ny = min (y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(nx,ny, mx,my) # keeps the rectangle from changing size
for i in range(1,n):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'k.')
    plt.pause(0.001)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).